# Magento 2 - Error processing your request

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.0

anyone can help me why I am getting this error ? This error coming again and again on my website.

The configuration file has changed. Run the "app:config:import" or the "setup:upgrade" command to synchronize the configuration.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: have you tried running the commands? If yes, what was the output?

Answer (score 0):

This happens after you change `app/etc/config.php` file. You need to reimport configurations from `app/etc/config.php` file to your database by running the below command.

> php bin/magento app:config:import

Thanks